# Scanner fraction Sum "Formula"

Tags: java

So what this problem in the book is asking me to do is to write a method with a parameter N and what it should print is

1   when I call printFractionSum(1)

and when I call printFractionSum(5) it does

1+(1/2)+(1/3)+(1/4)+(1/5)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  printfractionSums(5);
}

public static void printfractionSums(int n) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= n-1; i++) {
    System.out.print(1 "+" 1/n-i);
  }
}
```

That is what I have so far and I don't know how to go any further. Am I doing it right? Am I doing it wrong? I would really like to know how to do this so please tell me if you want me to reword the question.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029974/scanner-fractionsum-problem-finishing-part

Answer (score 0):

Define a `double` variable before entering the for loop, and use this to accumulate the sum of all terms.

Use `n` and not `n-1` as the limit in your `for` loop, so that it iterates `n` times.

In each iteration `i`, just add `1/i` to your result.